# Why the login screen still ask for a password after remove it?

Tags: 12.04, login, password

I removed my password and now when I go to the login screen it asks for one and my old password wont work.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried just pressing enter without enter **any** character?

Comment: Yes and it wont work.

Comment: You can try [reseting your admin password](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/62483). If that doesn't work for you, let us know